# How do I modify the internal buffer of std::cin

Tags: c++, buffer, cin, overwrite

I am writing a software that grabs a password using `std::cin`

However unlikely, i am trying to avoid the possibility that the password get paged to the disk from memory so I want to modify the buffer of `std::cin` to overwrite the password as soon as I'm done with it.

right now i have this:

```
std::cin.clear();
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
std::cin.rdbuf(ss.rdbuf());
std::cin.clear();
```

but I'm pretty sure this is bad since it doesn't take into account the current size of the cin buffer.
How do i properly overwrite the contents of the buffer?

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `gptr()` and `egptr()` to get the beginning and end of the buffer.

Edit: As Charles Bailey pointed out, these are protected. My assumption is that if you want a stream buffer that you can clear its contents at a specified time, that you'd be implementing one of your own that derives from one of the standard stream buffer classes, but provides a `clear()` member (or whatever name you find convenient). Changing the contents of the buffer without the buffer manager knowing about it will generally be a rather bad thing...

Comment: `gptr()` and `egptr()` are protected so unless you're writing the streambuf class that the implementations std::cin is actually using initially this isn't going to help, unless I'm not understanding your answer?

Answer (score 3):

Even if you scribble over the buffer immediately, it's still possible the password is written to disk.  A system i/o buffer might be paged to disk, as might the working memory which std::cin is in.  I used to develop forensic software which sniffed out exactly these conditions.

Comment: but wouldn't overwriting the buffer overwrite the same area of memory?

Comment: should it not be possible to tell the kernel to make a certain alligned page not to illegible for disk paging ?

Comment: @Jorge:  the point is that even if the password is in memory for just one instruction cycle, there's a possibility it will be paged to disk.  @Vainstah:  that's possible with the program copy of the stream buffer, and maybe even the runtime library's copy, but what about the system's i/o buffers?  There's no way to know where those are.

Comment: forensics: 1  developer: 0     ::cheering::